# Use GetEnumSelectList<T> while only showing preselected values

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Is there any way to use GetEnumSelectList while the Dropdownlist is only populated with items I can select beforehand?
All examples I found work with Viewbag or some other workaround, but I'm hoping there is a cleaner solution.

This is how I use it in the view and it shows all the values in the enum:

```
<select asp-for="evOwner.evpriority" class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<EVOwnerType>()">
                                    <option selected="selected" value="">please select</option>
</select>
```

This is my enumeration and I only want to show guest and vip to be selected in the dropdownlist:

```
public enum EVOwnerType
{
    [Display(Name = "")]
    employee = 0,
    [Display(Name = "")]
    vip = 1,
    [Display(Name = "")]
    guest = 2,
    [Display(Name = "")]
    notDriver = 3
}
```

Comment: `GetEnumSelectList<T>` returns a set of `SelectListItem` objects which does not contain the original type-safe `enum` values, that's why people prefer to put them in the `ViewModel` instead.

Comment: In .NET, enum members should be `PascalCased`, not `camelCased`.

Comment: You **need** to include the current value of `evOwner.evpriority` in the list of rendered `<option>` values, even if it isn't `vip` or `guest`, otherwise you will break existing records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use Linq extension methods in `asp-` attributes.
- But because `SelectListItem` does not contain the raw enum values, you'll need to use `Int32.Parse` or `Int32.TryParse` to get those values out.
- This will break if ASP.NET decides to render your enum values as text/strings instead of integers.

```
Html
    .GetEnumSelectList<EVOwnerType>()
    .Select( opt => ( opt, value: (EVOwnerType)Int32.Parse( opt.Value ) ) )
    .Where( t => t.value == EVOwnerType.vip || t.value == EVOwnerType.guest || t.value == this.Model.evOwner.evpriority )
    .Select( t => t.opt )
```

This will need to be packed into a single line:

```
<select asp-for="evOwner.evpriority" class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<EVOwnerType>().Select( opt => ( opt, value: (EVOwnerType)Int32.Parse( opt.Value ) ) ).Where( t => t.value == EVOwnerType.vip || t.value == EVOwnerType.guest || t.value == this.Model.evOwner.evpriority ).Select( t => t.opt )">
    <option selected="selected" value="">please select</option>
</select>
```

...which isn't pretty.

Which is why you really should generate the list separately (either in your controller action, or in a `@{}` code block in your view).

---

#### Alternatively: Generating the list in a Razor code-block in the view:

Consider this alternative:

```
@{
    List<SelectListItem> enumItems = this.Html.GetEnumSelectList<EVOwnerType>()
        .Select( opt => ( opt, value: (EVOwnerType)Int32.Parse( opt.Value ) ) )
        .Where( t => t.value == EVOwnerType.vip || t.value == EVOwnerType.guest || t.value == this.Model.evOwner.evpriority )
        .Select( t => t.opt )
        .ToList();
}

<!-- etc -->

<select asp-for="evOwner.evpriority" class="form-control" asp-items="enumItems">
    <option selected="selected" value="">please select</option>
</select>
```

Much better!

Comment: thanks for your help, I use it in a create view, so the value of in (t.value == this.Model.evOwner.evpriority ) is not set yet, which is why it threw an exception, but without that part it works